# How to integrade MoinMoin into Pyramid?

Tags: python, wsgi, moinmoin

Does anyone know how to integrate MoinMoin into Pyramide? Are there any manuals? The similarity of this [pylons+moinmoin](http://wiki.pylonshq.com/display/pylonscookbook/A+Pylons+controller+with+MoinMoin+as+a+WSGI+callable)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You maybe want to ask about "how to integrate any WSGI app into pyramid".

If that is answered, you can apply that to moin as it is just a WSGI app.